# window.innerWidth - workaround for when it returns the wrong value

Tags: javascript, dom, layout

- Some JavaScript libraries relies on window `innerWidth` and `innerHeight` to do their calculations
- `window.innerWidth` is not 100% reliable, which may lead to bugs
- `matchMedia().matches` is 100% accurate but it returns a boolean value
- come around: use `matchMedia` to verify `window.innerWidth` value; if it returns false use `matchMedia` to do a binary search until it finds the correct value

I faced that issue with some libs that relies on `window.innerWidth`. In cases where I had some media queries the return value of `window.innerWidth` used by the library would be off and that library would have issues with incorrect value.

I've seen that `matchMedia().matches` always return the correct value, but it returns a boolean value, not the width value. I've not seen a solution so far for that (maybe some of you know a better solution?), so I came up with a solution using `matchMedia`.

I created a function `getCorrectDimension` that performs a binary search around the window `innerWidth` (or `innerHeight`) to find the correct value if its value is wrong as you can see below:

```
const binarySearch = dim => function bin(start, end) {
    const guess = Math.floor((start + end)/2)

    // this checks if we have the correct value, if not it will keep calling itself until there's a match
    if(window.matchMedia(`(${dim}: ${guess}px)`).matches) {
        return guess
    }

    // since it is not a match, then we need to recalibrate the range and call again.
    // for that we check the boolean value using with min-width (height) rule.
    return window.matchMedia(`(min-${dim}: ${guess}px)`).matches 
        ? bin(guess, end) 
        : bin(start, guess)
}

const getCorrectDimension = (dim = 'width', range = 300) => {
    if(dim !== 'width' && dim !== 'height') {
        throw Error('`getCorrectDimension` accepts "width" or "height" as parameter')
    }

    let prop = 'inner' + dim.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + dim.slice(1)

    // here checks if the window.innerWidth or Height it's the correct one
    if(window.matchMedia(`(${dim}: ${window[prop]}px)`).matches) {
        return window[prop]
    }

    // here, since the value is wrong we use binarySearch to find its correct value
    const start = window[prop] - range >= 0 ? window[prop] - range : 0
    const end = window[prop] + range

    return binarySearch(dim)(start, end)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

<strike>I have never seen `innerWidth` or `innerHeight` report the wrong value. There are a few bugs listed for chrome and firefox but they are all closed.</strike>

<strike>Could you provide any evidence?</strike>

## UPDATE

Media query matches down to fractions of a CSS pixel while `innerWidth` returns integer CSS pixel values. This is a problem when `devicePixelRatio !== devicePixelRatio | 0`

I tried to find a cover all solution, but too much time need to complete so I withdraw the answers content.

Comment: example of the issue: at [link](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/animation/) if you attach an event listener like `window.addEventListener('resize', () => console.log(window.innerWidth))`, you can see `window.innerWidth` value make jumps around 950px, a place with a media query breakpoint. you can play around and look into other sites. I started to look recently into this when checking an issue opened at `react-sizes` [link](https://github.com/renatorib/react-sizes/issues/32).

Comment: @buzatto The only way i can get `innerWidth` to not match the media query is to use a zoom that results in a  fractional pixel size such that `matchMedia(`(min-width: ${innerWidth-1}px) and (max-width: ${innerWidth+1}px)`).matches` is true but `matchMedia(`(width: ${innerWidth}px)`).matches` is false. It's not `innerWidth`  that is at fault but the media query. The spec is ambiguous, I will update answer when i have done further research. As it stands searching for a matching integer size will fail if `devicePixelRatio !== devicePixelRatio | 0` or the scroll bar size has the same condition.

Comment: you said that it had bugs related to chrome and firefox before, but not anymore. I mostly use chrome on daily basis, I tested now on firefox and edge, no apparent issue on them everything is fine, but on chrome there is 16 px jump on average on that example link. I also have a personal project and only on chrome I see jumps as well, not on firefox or edge.

Comment: @buzatto Your code as it is in the question can fail if the `range` argument is smaller than the error eg `innerWidth` reports 1000, media query passes 1016 and `range` is 10. Also fails on latest Chrome (win10) on some `devicePixelRatio` non integer values. Eg `devicePixelRatio = 1.100000036` (menu setting 110%)  the media query matched 1427.6px but not 1428px the closest integer value (I forget the exact values). When it fails it throws a call stack overflow.